# Correctly remove second json.Marshal in Go

Tags: mysql, json, rest, go

I have, for whatever reason, while trying to build a simple Rest API in Go with MySQL storage, added a second json.Marshal which is double-encoding and producing results with escaped quotes and such. I could strip the quotes, but I think I shouldn't have two json.Marshal things happening in the first place.

The problem is twofold - 1) which is proper to remove (leaning toward the first because "result" should be the larger array) and 2)how to keep the code functioning after removal?  I can't just simply remove the first one as I start encountering all sorts of errors. Here are the relevant portions of the code:

```
type Volume struct {
    Id int
    Name string
    Description string
}
```

... skipping ahead ....

```
var result = make([]string,1000)
switch request.Method {
    case "GET":

        name  := request.URL.Query().Get("name")

        stmt, err := db.Prepare("select id, name, description from idm_assets.VOLUMES where name = ?")
            if err != nil{
                fmt.Print( err );
            }

            rows, err := stmt.Query(name)

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Print( err )
            }

            i := 0

            for rows.Next() {
                var name string
                var id int
                var description string
                err = rows.Scan( &id, &name, &description )
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error scanning: " + err.Error())
                        return
                }
                volume := &Volume{Id: id,Name:name,Description: description}
```

Here is the first json.Marshal ...

```
                b, err := json.Marshal(volume)
                    fmt.Println(b)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    return
                }
                result[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(b))
                i++
            }
        result = result[:i]
```

...skipping other cases for PUT, DELETE, Etc. To the second json.Marshal ...

```
default:
    }
json, err := json.Marshal(result)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintf(response,"'%v'\n",string(json) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `result` into an array of `*Volume`

```
result := []*Volume{}
```

and then append new `Volume` records:

```
result = append(result, &Volume{Id: id,Name:name,Description: description})
```

and in the end use `Marshal(result)` to get the JSON result.

Comment: Thank you so much. That definitely got me going int he right direction. I had previously attempted appending to the slice, but was doing it incorrectly and couldn't see the error until comparing with this. Thanks!